# xamarin application not being able to deploy

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-virtual-device, vs-community-edition

I have installed Visual Studio Community 2015 and Xamarin. My application is not being able to deploy. List of pre-populated devices are also not showing.
[no prepopulated device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxXaw.png)

List of android virtual devices is empty
[no avd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1SfW.png)

I am not able to even create a new avd. When I try to create a new avd the OK button stays disabled.

Please tell me how I can create a avd and deploy my application.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Xamarin Android Player or Visual Studio Android Emulator.

Comment: I am getting a setup blocked message - this computer does not support the windows phone emulator, which requires 64-bit edition of windows 8.1 pro and a computer that supports hyper-v.

Comment: I got Xamarin Android Player to work but had to decrease the memory from virtualbox.

Comment: If memory is say 2gb then error is given. Is there some solution for this?